# chrome + edge border trails on scale animation

Tags: google-chrome, css-animations, microsoft-edge

Have I found a browser bug??
**update**: yes I have. Bug submitted at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1169075.

A css `scale` animation is leaving a trail when `border` or `outline` properties are added to this `<div>`. Surely I'm not doing this wrong. This happens on Chrome and Edge (they use the same engine these days I believe).

No problems on Chrome for Mac.

Chrome 87.0.4280.141
Edge 87.0.664.75

```css
@keyframes sqwhere-hover {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  50% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    ;
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}


.sqwhere {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  animation: sqwhere-hover 2s infinite;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="sqwhere"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to test the issue with the **MS Edge Chromium** and **Google Chrome** browser. I can reproduce the said issue.

As the issue is reproducible in both Edge and Chrome browsers, possibly the issue is related to the **Chromium** browser engine.

In my test results, I noticed that issue only occurs when we pass the `transform: scale` value as 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, etc.

A quick workaround for this issue is to pass the `transform: scale` value as 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, etc.

**Example:**

```
50% {              
         transform: scale(1.5);                
    }
```

**Test result in Edge browser with scale(1.5):**

[image]

Further, I suggest you create a new issue on the [Chromium issues site](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) and try to provide detailed information about this issue.

Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak-MSFT. I'll report the issue. If you look closely, even the .5 fix isn't quite right. It's cutting faint white squares into the light grey background.

Comment: Submitted the bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1169075. I'll update my post. Thanks again.